# message lost when multiple nodes publish to one topic

Tags: ros

Now I have two kind of nodelets, first I have 4 camera node which capture images and then published through one same topic, then I have a process node which get messages from the topic to process. I'm sure that the processing node is 4 times faster than the capture rate. But I still get 10-20% message lost. In subscribe side, I already used tcp transport, following is my message setting：

**camera node** （four nodes in total， the capture fps is 25）

```
m_pub = it.advertise("/camera/out_topic", 25);
```

**Processing node**

```
m_sub = nh.subscribe(in_topic.c_str(), 400, &Detection::imageCB, this,                                                                        
                     ros::TransportHints()                                                                             
                     .reliable()                                                                                       
                     .tcpNoDelay(true));
```

**It't my fault, the process is not faster than the capture frequency**

Comment: please put your codes

Comment: Is the queue of the subscriber large enough?

Comment: @Benyamin Jafari I have uploaded the code

Comment: Do you really need to publish on the same topic? can you use from four various topics with the same CallBack function? You could also use the mutex for handle it.

Comment: @Benyamin Jafari I can distinguish the camera message with header, not need the mutex. I just to do process in a batch mode with NN network

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem Is the Timestamp Of Images,Your Publishers publish data at Exact Timestamp and Some Messages Will get lost when that happens.
I suggest You use Some sort Of sync for your nodes 
are You using `rate.sleep` in your publishers ?

Comment: How to sync each node? by the way i have already set the images with different frame_id in the message header. And the capture rate  depends on the rtsp capture rate

Comment: I have seen Sync with no timestamp difference For 2 Cameras In `uvc_camera` stereo node i suggest u start there and try to implement it for 4 cameras and add small delay for each camera.and also Frame_id Dosen't Affect the transport, its just a mean to identify the frame the camera sends its data. in ROS framework if u don't specify any rate.sleep(or any ros based sleep functions to limit the output of publisher) That publisher will Send Data on topic as much as it can.